# Converting TIGER/Line Shapefiles to GeoJSON doesn't use long/lat

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson, tiger

I downloaded a file of California geographic boundaries based on the US Census Bureau's 2016 MAF/TIGER database (https://data.ca.gov/dataset/ca-geographic-boundaries).

I'm attempting to convert this dataset to GeoJSON so I can use it in Leaflet.

Despite several attempts to convert the data, the final location coordinates aren't converting to longitude and latitude.

Instead, they use a different scale based on much larger numbers.
`[ -13186463.85473, 4067122.65072 ]` is an example.

This is from the converted format of one of the features:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "06", "PLACEFP": "66140", "PLACENS": "02411785", "GEOID": "0666140", "NAME": "San Fernando", "NAMELSAD": "San Fernando city", "LSAD": "25", "CLASSFP": "C1", "PCICBSA": "N", "PCINECTA": "N", "MTFCC": "G4110", "FUNCSTAT": "A", "ALAND": 6148697, "AWATER": 0, "INTPTLAT": "+34.2886519", "INTPTLON": "-118.4362413" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -13186463.85473, 4067122.65072 ], [ -13186256.02122, 4067306.28803 ], [ -13186074.57043, 4067466.75418 ], [ -13186075.79495, 4067471.73931 ], [ -13186012.12019, 4067525.76749 ], [ -13185997.20338, 4067538.43249 ], [ -13185977.72246, 4067554.87006 ], [ -13185973.26968, 4067558.77736 ], [ -13185945.55113, 4067583.83797 ], [ -13185862.17282, 4067659.42435 ], [ -13185851.48615, 4067668.99058 ], [ -13185818.20162, 4067697.01563 ], [ -13185769.22104, 4067738.24491 ], [ -13185746.40054, 4067757.37751 ], [ -13185737.49498, 4067765.0575 ], [ -13185732.81956, 4067768.83013 ], [ -13185757.53249, 4067806.42177 ], [ -13185771.00215, 4067826.90185 ], [ -13185795.26981, 4067863.81999 ], [ -13185759.87021, 4067902.08564 ], [ -13185712.67074, 4067953.01687 ], [ -13185662.91092, 4068006.50839 ], [ -13185605.47006, 4068068.08458 ], [ -13185577.52886, 4068086.13981 ], [ -13185474.44701, 4068201.07414 ], [ -13185463.31506, 4068220.74648 ], [ -13185294.10942, 4068403.05416 ], [ -13185262.49467, 4068370.71556 ], [ -13185258.82113, 4068367.07747 ], [ -13185238.89494, 4068347.53962 ], [ -13185214.07068, 4068321.8036 ], [ -13185204.71984, 4068330.96616 ], [ -13185079.48541, 4068466.24946 ], [ -13185080.042, 4068483.09262 ], [ -13185064.45727, 4068499.93579 ], [ -13185068.46478, 4068504.11291 ], [ -13185004.45606, 4068566.09605 ], [ -13184997.33162, 4068573.37235 ], [ -13184990.54113, 4068580.24442 ], [ -13184984.19591, 4068587.11649 ], [ -13184965.38292, 4068607.46324 ], [ -13184957.14527, 4068598.43521 ], [ -13184954.47361, 4068601.39964 ], [ -13184880.89142, 4068680.76575 ], [ -13184714.91404, 4068859.84684 ], [ -13184550.60646, 4069037.17899 ], [ -13184383.07061, 4069218.01753 ], [ -13184304.813, 4069302.3739 ], [ -13184261.17575, 4069349.53828 ], [ -13184225.99879, 4069386.7309 ], [ -13184220.09886, 4069393.33395 ], [ -13184211.1933, 4069403.44066 ], [ -13184135.83, 4069484.83376 ], [ -13184053.00829, 4069574.31293 ], [ -13183970.18658, 4069663.65805 ], [ -13183887.36487, 4069753.13864 ], [ -13183854.63694, 4069788.44594 ], [ -13183838.49561, 4069771.19656 ], [ -13183810.99968, 4069739.39309 ], [ -13183782.61321, 4069712.84535 ], [ -13183729.06852, 4069655.84203 ], [ -13183720.60824, 4069646.13936 ], [ -13183717.49129, 4069642.50087 ], [ -13183709.47628, 4069634.01105 ], [ -13183691.8878, 4069615.41432 ], [ -13183606.72837, 4069525.80007 ], [ -13183599.15864, 4069517.71461 ], [ -13183493.07114, 4069404.38401 ], [ -13183485.16746, 4069395.35534 ], [ -13183324.31075, 4069211.95367 ], [ -13183162.78613, 4069027.61171 ], [ -13182841.40668, 4068661.22749 ], [ -13182611.42056, 4068398.87727 ], [ -13182459.91472, 4068532.94868 ], [ -13182295.38449, 4068678.60997 ], [ -13182264.21503, 4068643.03664 ], [ -13182259.76225, 4068638.051 ], [ -13181987.02943, 4068326.92408 ], [ -13182303.17681, 4068047.06533 ], [ -13182299.05799, 4068042.34943 ], [ -13182254.53018, 4067991.4178 ], [ -13182171.3745, 4067897.63952 ], [ -13182166.8104, 4067893.46263 ], [ -13182135.19566, 4067857.35282 ], [ -13182171.3745, 4067825.41999 ], [ -13182531.93837, 4067507.17447 ], [ -13182536.61379, 4067503.13246 ], [ -13182541.06657, 4067499.09045 ], [ -13182721.84944, 4067339.43223 ], [ -13182816.47102, 4067255.89887 ], [ -13182902.74363, 4067179.77626 ], [ -13183086.53213, 4067017.56272 ], [ -13183267.09236, 4066858.18074 ], [ -13183484.27671, 4066667.00616 ], [ -13183631.99769, 4066536.05546 ], [ -13183628.65811, 4066531.87907 ], [ -13183635.89387, 4066522.31381 ], [ -13183838.16141, 4066293.154 ], [ -13183844.3953, 4066286.28332 ], [ -13183850.62919, 4066279.54737 ], [ -13183860.42531, 4066269.174 ], [ -13183869.77615, 4066259.60895 ], [ -13183876.90059, 4066252.46886 ], [ -13183887.25331, 4066242.63439 ], [ -13183897.71734, 4066232.79993 ], [ -13183908.29269, 4066223.23492 ], [ -13183970.96557, 4066167.86577 ], [ -13183982.09752, 4066158.16609 ], [ -13184013.04435, 4066175.14053 ], [ -13184025.95741, 4066189.28591 ], [ -13184131.71095, 4066310.26334 ], [ -13184190.48766, 4066377.48855 ], [ -13184204.51392, 4066369.1359 ], [ -13184228.33629, 4066346.90709 ], [ -13184228.67025, 4066344.07797 ], [ -13184229.11553, 4066341.11414 ], [ -13184225.33066, 4066333.43511 ], [ -13184233.90226, 4066323.73529 ], [ -13184252.3813, 4066309.18558 ], [ -13184268.96791, 4066292.21094 ], [ -13184279.7659, 4066284.26251 ], [ -13184330.86155, 4066239.13167 ], [ -13184402.77395, 4066175.67937 ], [ -13184471.01281, 4066115.46064 ], [ -13184504.18602, 4066086.22706 ], [ -13184544.26104, 4066050.79659 ], [ -13184555.39299, 4066040.9623 ], [ -13184581.21911, 4066018.19527 ], [ -13184603.81697, 4065998.25732 ], [ -13184617.84323, 4065985.86348 ], [ -13184686.63868, 4065925.24161 ], [ -13184762.78122, 4065858.01907 ], [ -13184834.80494, 4065794.56891 ], [ -13184906.82866, 4065730.98439 ], [ -13184976.51467, 4065669.4209 ], [ -13185050.76477, 4065603.95113 ], [ -13185097.51897, 4065560.84367 ], [ -13185105.75661, 4065570.27341 ], [ -13185234.33065, 4065717.24369 ], [ -13185370.14047, 4065872.56816 ], [ -13185452.18295, 4065966.32967 ], [ -13185466.43185, 4065982.76496 ], [ -13185643.76384, 4066185.37898 ], [ -13185782.02268, 4066343.53899 ], [ -13185920.50416, 4066501.97065 ], [ -13186030.37653, 4066627.532 ], [ -13186056.31398, 4066657.9795 ], [ -13186083.03066, 4066687.61873 ], [ -13186095.72109, 4066702.16892 ], [ -13186124.66416, 4066737.4667 ], [ -13186147.92994, 4066761.85187 ], [ -13186204.1463, 4066826.25052 ], [ -13186240.43646, 4066867.74608 ], [ -13186322.8129, 4066961.78528 ], [ -13186325.03929, 4066962.32419 ], [ -13186328.60152, 4066960.43801 ], [ -13186334.72409, 4066972.69819 ], [ -13186343.40701, 4066985.4973 ], [ -13186378.91794, 4067026.18507 ], [ -13186384.48392, 4067032.51729 ], [ -13186392.83288, 4067041.94826 ], [ -13186406.30254, 4067057.03782 ], [ -13186427.11929, 4067081.15422 ], [ -13186463.85473, 4067122.65072 ] ] ] ] } }
```

I've tried three different approaches to convert the file, and the different coordinate system remains in all 3.

1. Using QGIS to convert the file based on this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9648vyQEFM&ab_channel=MikeMiller)
2. https://mapshaper.org/
3. https://ogre.adc4gis.com/

I assume that this is just a coordinate type I'm unfamiliar with, and I need to account for it when converting the datatypes. But I'm new to this and can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. The coordinates were in EPSG:3857 WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator, and I needed to convert them to EPSG:4326 WGS 84. I was able to do this by changing the CRS value when exporting the layer in QGIS.